# How are global variables in shared libraries linked?

Tags: c++, c, linux, dll

Suppose I have shared library with this function where "i" is some global variable.

```
int foo() {
return i++;
}
```

When I call this function from multiple processes the value of "i" in each process is independent on the other processes.

This behavior is quite expected.

I was just wondering how is usually this behavior implemented by the linker? From my understanding the code is shared between processes, so the variable has to have the same virtual address in all address spaces of every program that uses this library. That condition seems quite difficult to accomplish to me so I guess I am missing something here and it is done differently.

Can I get some more detailed info on this subject?

Comment: **Code** is shared, not **data.** The dynamic linker presumably creates a new copy of the variable for each process, but it doesn't make copies of the text (code) segment.

Comment: @H2CO3 I am well aware of that. However I am asking on the details of the linking process.

Comment: Well, if you need more details, I think you should take a look at an actual implementation. The dynamic linker in Linux and the one in Darwin (BSD/OS X/iOS) are opensource.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing)

Answer (score 8):

The dynamic linking process at run time (much the same as the static linking process), allocates separate data (and bss) segments for each process, and maps those into the process address space. Only the text segments are shared between processes. This way, each process gets its own copy of static data.

Comment: And is it necessary to allocate the data segments into exactly the same location in every address space? If so, what happens if the location is already used by some other data in one of the spaces?

Comment: The segments are allocated, mapped to the address space somewhere (whatever is available), and then a link process if performed (relocation etc. and symbol resolution).

Comment: But if the code is shared, how can I perform relocation on it without affecting other processes that use the same code?

Comment: The code is shared in the sense that there is a single copy of it in physical memory. The data, as I have pointed out, is not shared (separate segments are allocated). The code and data may be mapped to different virtual addresses in each process. The link process happens against these virtual addresses.

Comment: I have now done a quick test and really the address of the variable is different in each process. However I still don't quite understand that if there is a single copy of the code, how is it then possible to work with 2 different addresses?

Comment: I think I got it. http://www.shorestreet.com/why-your-dso-is-slow according to this article there is also a similar thing as vtable present. That also means that the code in the shared library is compiled diferently (PIC) than normal non-shared code. Thats it right?

Comment: Relocation unshares the code.  When the loader detects that relocation is necessary, it makes a copy of the code segment and then writes to that copy as it processes fixups.

Comment: @HonzaBrabec Shared library code is compiled as position independent code, which means the generated code only uses relative, not absolute addresses to do stuff. And global symbols that must be addressed by an absolute address is patched by the dynamic linker (when the library is loaded at runtime) to the relocated addresses. Keep in mind that virtual memory is in effect too - the addresses may very well be the  same, the OS can map physical memory to dffeent virtual addresses in each process, and vice versa.

Comment: @nos maybe you shall write that as an answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

> the code is shared between processes, so the variable has to have the
>   same virtual address in all address spaces of every program that uses
>   this library

The code is not shared the way you think. Yes the dynamic shared object is loaded only once but the memory references or the stack or the heap that code in the `so` uses is not shared. Only the section that contains the code is shared.

Answer (score 0):

Each process has it's own unique address space, so when a process access the variable it can have different values then the other process. If the process should share the same memory, they would have to specifically set this up. A shared library is not enough for that.

Comment: I am aware of the thing that each process has unique address space. However, the code is shared. and the code refers to some address (virtual) in the memory. My question is about how that thing is handled.

Comment: But even though they point to the same address, the memory pages are relative to their process environment. The memory pages are assigned by the operating system, so the linker doesn't have to do anything special for this.